# Org Mode Table Columns Misaligned

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I recently moved to a Lenovo Thinkpad running Arch Linux. Emacs on this machine doesn't align my org-mode columns properly.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: messed up Org Mode tables]

I'm using...

- a monospaced-font.
- Emacs Version = 25.3.1 of 2017-12-04
- Orgmode version = 9.1.6

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: The font for the dates is clearly not fixed width. Compare Mon and Sat.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a monospaced font?  The was "Sat" aligns with "Mon" on the next line doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I was setting the default font but not the frame font as monospaced.